# MySQL: How to "order by" a subquery column while also using a parent query "order by"?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sql-order-by, multiple-columns

1. I have two tables.
2. They both have date and item_id columns.
3. I'm inner joining them on item_id.
4. The results should be ordered by both date columns together
5. The code below works, producing the correct result set...
6. However they are only ordered by the first table's date

Code

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM   table_one_items t1
       INNER JOIN (SELECT t2.item_id,
                          t2.date_favorited
                   FROM   table_two_favorites t2
                   WHERE  t2.user_id IN( 1, 2, 3 )) t3
               ON t1.item_id = t3.item_id
                   OR t1.user_id IN( 1, 2, 3 )
WHERE  t1.published = 1
GROUP  BY t1.item_id
ORDER  BY t3.date_favorited DESC,
          t1.date_created DESC
```

**Question:**

I'm looking for the items in `chronological order` despite coming from a table and a `subquery` table with their own date columns. How do I go about doing this?

**What I've tried:**

I have tried moving the `t3.date` around and ordering the `subquery` itself but that doesn't work. Any attempt to modify the subquery changes the result set, and I can't think of another way to write it to get the same results but with the correct ordering. I'm aware there might be a better way to write this query, but I haven't been able to figure that out either. I feel lucky this works!

Additional Info:

The first table is an index of all items, while the second table is a "favorites" table that only includes items that have been favorited by users. With `t1.item_id = t3.item_id OR t1.user_id IN(1,2,3)` I'm essentially getting items in t1 that are made by these users OR items that have been favorited by these users.

Examples:

**Table One "Item Table":** (Date is "date created")

```
item_id 1 user_id 2 date_created 2015-01-1 00:00:00
item_id 2 user_id 2 date_created 2015-01-3 00:00:00
item_id 3 user_id 1 date_created 2015-01-5 00:00:00
item_id 4 user_id 3 date_created 2015-01-7 00:00:00
```

**Table Two "User Favorites":** (Date is "date favorited")

```
item_id 2 user_id 2 date_favorited 2015-01-6 00:00:00
item_id 1 user_id 2 date_favorited 2015-01-6 00:00:00
item_id 1 user_id 3 date_favorited 2015-01-8 00:00:00
```

Desired Results:

```
item_id 3 (ordered by date_created: 2015-01-5 00:00:00)
item_id 4 (ordered by date_created: 2015-01-7 00:00:00)
item_id 2 (ordered by date_favorited: 2015-01-6 00:00:00)
item_id 1 (ordered by date_favorited: 2015-01-8 00:00:00)
```

Current Results:

```
item_id 1 (ordered by date_created)
item_id 2 (ordered by date_created)
item_id 3 (ordered by date_created)
item_id 4 (ordered by date_created)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. (And I'll be sure to mark the answer!)

Comment: can you edit the question with sample data expected output.

Comment: Example tables added.

Comment: Can you use a `SPROC ` ? I mean its a long way, but you can insert value from one table and then from another so they will be ordered by table dates.

Comment: now it is more confusing. Desired and current results are totally contradicting not only the order.

Comment: I've gone back and redone the tables. Let me know if that is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a CASE statement in the ORDER BY to select which date you want, so:

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE
        WHEN t3.date > t1.date AND t3.item_id = t1.item_id THEN t3.date
        ELSE t1.date
    END DESC
```

If you want to sort by the maximum of the two dates. However I'm not sure your subquery would be doing what you expect; unless items created by the user are always in table_two regardless of whether they had favorited them

Comment: This works! There's just one thing missing from your answer. (Edit it in and I'll accept it! :) ) In the WHEN it should be `t3.date > t1.date AND t3.item_id = t1.item_id`. That seemed to do the trick for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just to add to this so the answer is even more clear - items are always in table_one, but not always in table_two. Yet the subquery seems to work. How did you mean by the sub-query possibly not doing what was expected?

Comment: You are doing an inner join which means must be in both tables

Comment: In this case, table one contains references to all the items in table two (think of it as an index), but table two doesn't contain all the items in table one. That subquery (table three) will always return items that can be found in table one, and so inner joining table one and table three, will always "match up" or "intersect" with the items in table one. 


`Table 1 (T1) {
id 1
id 2
id 3
id 4 }`    


`Subquery Results Table (T3)  {
id 2  
id 3 }` 


`Inner join (ON t1.id = t3.id) results:  
{Table One rows: 2, 3 }`


But let me know if I've made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try following with order by clause:

```
ORDER BY 
    COALESCE(t3.date,t1.date) DESC;
```

Above query can help ordering for your requirements though you have opportunity to tune your SQL.

Comment: Sadly this didn't work - the resulting order was all jumbled into a pattern I couldn't determine. I think because there needs to be linkage between t3.item_id = t1.item_id. See my comment to BenAdams answer for example. I would be interested in seeing if this could work although I have a feeling Ben's answer might be better for performance. Maybe?

Comment: COLEACE was added to refer t1.date in case of t3.date assuming that t3.date will be null if table_two doesn't have value. It can't address additional condition (i.e. t3.item_id=t1.item_id), case ... end would be the good solution in your context.